# Como elmino todos los comentarios de un documento HTML, CSS o JS? Uso Atom

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Como puedo eliminar todos los comentarios de un documento sin tener que ir uno a uno eliminando? Se podria hacer con expresiones regulares?

Comment: Puedes usar algo así como Regex `<!--.+-->`

Comment: hay un regex bastante completo en https://stackoverflow.com/a/5989450/1423096

Answer (score 0):

En Atom presiona <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> para abrir el buscador de texto en un archivo, activa el Regex representada por este icono <kbd>.*</kbd> y en *Find in current buffer* escribe esto:

- HTML: `<!--.+-->`
- JS Linea simple: `//.+`
- JS Multi linea: [No se puede aún con Atom](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/398)
- CSS: `/\*.+\*/`

Answer (score 0):

En Atom tal y como dices puedes usar expresiones regulares usando .* y luego añade:

`(\/\*[\w\'\s\r\n\*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[\w\s\']*)|(\<![\-\-\s\w\>\/]*\>)`

La expresión lo que hará es encontrar todos los comentarios y reemplazarlos con nada.

Otra manera de no tener que borrarlo todo uno a uno sería seleccionar el símbolo de comentario del lenguage e ir seleccionandolos con Ctrl+D y borrar todas las líneas seleccionadas con Ctrl+Shift+K